# Emacs mail mode copy sent messages

Tags: email, emacs, msmtp

In Mail-mode (`C-x m`) how can I get a copy of sent messages saved in my IMAP Sent folder? I am using `msmtp` to send mail. I have the Arch Linux `msmtp-mta` package installed so that it can use the `sendmail` command as an alias to `msmtp`. In my `init.el` I have `(setq mail-user-agent 'sendmail-user-agent)`. I'm not sure if I need to configure Emacs or something on my mail server in order to get a copy of sent messages saved.

Comment: Do you have an option for an `Fcc` field -- like Cc or Bcc?  In Wanderlust, I use `Fcc:  %INBOX.Sent` as one of my fields -- similar to From, To, Cc, Bcc, Subject, and Fcc.

Comment: @lawlist from [the docs](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/emacs/html_chapter/emacs_29.html) it seems that option is used to append a copy to a local file. I want to have a copy stored on the server so that I can always find it in the /Sent folder.

Comment: My example does both (in Wanderlust, that is) -- server and local.  And, I use IMAP.

Comment: Just tried that and it saved a copy to ~/%INBOX.Sent locally but nothing on my IMAP server.

Comment: How about?:  *To send a blind carbon copy of every outgoing message to yourself, set the variable `mail-self-blind` to `t`. To send a blind carbon copy of every message to some other address, set the variable mail-default-headers to "Bcc: address\n". *  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Saving-a-copy-of-outgoing-mail.html

Comment: That does make a copy in my Inbox IMAP folder. Now is there any way to get it in the Sent folder?

Comment: There is a note on Wiki that it can't be done with gmail:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusGmail#toc11  I don't know what other servers share this type of limitation.  If you have your own website, then you can set up a filter / forwarding thing-a-mabob.  I think this is about as far as I can go, so I'll let the experts take it over from here.  If you don't find a satisfactory solution, you might want to give Wanderlust a try -- however, be prepared to spend a lot of time customizing it to your precise needs.

Comment: Here is something from the mailing list:  https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnus-english/2011-05/msg00043.html

Comment: I'm not using Gmail. Actually I was trying to switch from Mutt to something simpler like Mail mode and RMail, so I don't think I want something as complex as Wanderlust. Maybe Mail mode is too simple...

Comment: I just tried `mu4e` and it does the job of copying sent messages to the Sent IMAP folder perfectly. I guess I'll take the time to learn `mu4e` now, or at least keep using it to send emails.